# Can I create a WPF application with .net 5 preview?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-5

I am trying to create a .net 5 wpf application. Is this currently possible?

I Installed .net 5 sdk and the latest VS for Windows preview.

I cannot seem to find a template other than 4.x and .net core. This makes it seem like .NET 5 doesn't support this (yet)?

Is there a way to create a WPF application in .NET 5?

Comment: .NET 5 *is* .NET Core. The `Core` part was removed to make it look like .NET Old and .NET Core were merging, when in fact .NET Old is replaced by .NET Core and most APIs that were still missing from .NET Core were added in the .NET (Core) 5 wave

Comment: Try using the Core template and set the Target Template in the projects properties. Project->Properties->Application->Target Template.

Comment: @Kixoka the OP already found the templates but thought they aren't for .NET 5

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I get that, but that's why i said to go to properties and set the target framework in order to create a wpf app using .NET 5. This way he can actually create an application... as with any missing framework... there is an option to install the missing framework and by clicking that it brings up the web page with the .NET 5 and other frameworks that can be installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a WPF application in .NET 5?

Yes install the [Preview Version of Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) which until release of .Net 5, is the only version of VS which can build this type of app.

Note that it can be installed side by side with *non preview version* Visual studio.

---

**Preview Steps To Create**

Create a WPF project and select .Net Core:

[image]

Then verify its the version by doing properties on the project:

[image]

---

Note even though on the properties pages, the version control will list previous versions of .Net. That implies one could change, but moving it back causes too many errors; so I do not advise to try to downgrade back with a .Net Core WPF app.

Comment: As per today you can not even compile anything without the preview version as the lastest .nET 5 preview requires a new msbuild version.

Comment: Let's just hope they release this end of the month. Would be a shame to have to use a preview of VS (not supported) with a RC of .NET 5 (which DOES have go live)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers! To sum it all up: in the latest preview of Visual Studio for Windows I had to select WPF on .net core. With the WPF on .net (without core) I could only select 4.x and the .net core template already had .net 5 selected. There was no choosing which version from the template.